How can I get a specific property of an object using filter in Kotlin?
In Kotlin I have the following objects:
data class BugReport(
    val message: String,
    val bugItems: List<BugItem>,
)

And:
data class BugItem(
    val title: String,
    val checked: Boolean = false,
)

In a BugReport object, how can I get only the title property of those BugItems whose checked value is equal to true.
The idea is to get a comma separated string from the title.
I have this code:
val checkedTitles = bugReport.bugItems.filter(BugItem::checked).joinToString()

But with this code I get the complete BugItem objects, how can I get only the title property?

Use map for projections.

The last parameter of joinToString allows you to pass a function that transforms the objects to CharSequences, so you can do
val checkedTitles = bugReport.bugItems
    .filter(BugItem::checked)
    .joinToString { it.title }

If you want a List<String> containing the titles instead, you should use map to transform the objects.
// checkedTitles is of type List<String>
val checkedTitles = bugReport.bugItems
    .filter(BugItem::checked)
    .map(BugItem::title)


The first variant does not compile as is, it probably should be: .joinToString { it.title }

It has worked, but putting it as @DavidSoroko indicates in his comment: val checkedTitles = bugItems.filter(BugItem::checked).joinToString { it.title }. This creates a comma separated string which is what I needed. Thanks!
